# How do I copy a directory to a remote machine using Fabric?

Tags: python, fabric

I have a directory on my local machine that I would like to copy to a remote machine (and rename it) using Fabric. I know I can copy file using `put()`, but what about a directory. I know it's easy enough using **scp**, but I would prefer to do it from within my `fabfile.py` if possible.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You can use `put` for that as well (at least in 1.0.0):

> `local_path` may be a relative or absolute local file or **directory path**, and may contain **shell-style wildcards**, as understood by the Python **glob** module. Tilde expansion (as implemented by os.path.expanduser) is also performed.

See: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.0/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put

---

Update: This example works fine (for me) on 1.0.0.:

```
from fabric.api import env
from fabric.operations import run, put

env.hosts = ['frodo@middleearth.com']

def copy():
    # make sure the directory is there!
    run('mkdir -p /home/frodo/tmp')

    # our local 'testdirectory' - it may contain files or subdirectories ...
    put('testdirectory', '/home/frodo/tmp')

# [frodo@middleearth.com] Executing task 'copy'
# [frodo@middleearth.com] run: mkdir -p /home/frodo/tmp
# [frodo@middleearth.com] put: testdirectory/HELLO -> \
#     /home/frodo/tmp/testdirectory/HELLO
# [frodo@middleearth.com] put: testdirectory/WORLD -> \
#     /home/frodo/tmp/testdirectory/WORLD
# ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm getting an exception (Is a directory) any chance of an example?

Comment: @gaviscon_man: Added a (tested) example, but really it's just vanilla `fab`, no tricks. You'll get errors, if the target directories aren't in place already - so I included a simple `mkdir -p` before the `put`. (But other subdirectories, which are below the `testdirectory` will automatically created on the remote machine).

Comment: `put` is working. Will it support copying of folder with compress at source machine and decompress at remote machine.

Answer (score 33):

I would also look at the Project Tools module: fabric.contrib.project
[Documentation](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/project.html)

This has an `upload_project` function which takes a source and target directory.  Even better, there is an `rsync_project` function that uses rsync.  This is nice because it only updates the files that have changed and it accepts extra args like "exclude" which is nice for doing things like excluding your `.git` directory.

For example:

```
from fabric.contrib.project import rsync_project

def _deploy_ec2(loc):

    rsync_project(local_dir=loc, remote_dir='/var/www', exclude='.git')
```

Comment: `fabric.contrib.project` docs for latest version: http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/contrib/project.html

Comment: way better than `put/get`. also works perfectly for fetching user uploads from live websites, for example (`upload=False`, it's not obvious that it works in both ways).

Comment: i had to wrap the excluded dir in a list to get this to work: `exclude=['.git']`

Comment: This has been transfered to the `patchwork` library now: https://fabric-patchwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/transfers.html
See the other answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54667814/10190810

Answer (score 28):

For those using Fabric 2, `put` can no longer upload directories, only files. Also,  `rsync_project` is no longer part of the main Fabric package. The `contrib` package has been removed, [as explained here](http://www.fabfile.org/upgrading.html#contrib). Now, `rsync_project` has been renamed to `rsync`, and you need to install another package in order to be able to use it:

`pip install patchwork`

Now, assuming you already have created a connection to your server:

```
cxn = fabric.Connection('username@server:22')
```

You can use `rsync` as below:

```
import patchwork.transfers
patchwork.transfers.rsync(cxn, '/my/local/dir', target, exclude='.git')
```

Please refer to the [fabric-patchwork documentation](https://fabric-patchwork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/transfers.html#patchwork.transfers.rsync) for more information.

Comment: is there a way to provide automatic password to rsync?

Comment: @pg2455 Yes, using `connect_kwargs`. For example: `cxn = fabric.Connection('username@server:22', connect_kwargs=dict(password='yourpass'))`

Comment: @TGO Can you share any example on using put option to transfer file?

Comment: @Anish `put` can not upload in Fabric 2. If you're using Fabric 1, then please refer to the accepted answer. With Fabric 2 I use the example provided in the answer, using `rsync`.