# Copy folder with specific extension with fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I want to copy all a folder to the remote machine with `fabric`,
normally I can use the function `put`,
But I just want to copy python files in the folder and not `.pyc` files, so how can I process?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For remote mode you can retrieve only the *.py files* by putting:

```
find /some/path -name '*.py'
```

Comment: how do i merge this in a ``copy`` function? And does it create automatically new folder in the remote folder?

Comment: Check this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314711/python-how-do-i-copy-a-directory-to-a-remote-machine-using-fabric)

Comment: I've checked the example but could not find anything about file type filter in copy process...