# Capturing output of scp from python

Tags: python, django, scp

I have a django server, and I have to upload some data through scp. I have this view:

```
pathFile = '/home/user1/foo.json'
user = 'user1scp'
server = 'someserver.com'
pathServer = '/var/www/foo.json'

os.system("scp %s %s@%s:%s" % (pathFile, user, server, pathServer))
```

On the console window where the page is running (i.e. where I called the command 'runserver') I have this output shown:

```
[21/Jul/2016 18:55:12] "GET /someurl/upload HTTP/1.1" 301 0
foo.json                                          100%  609     0.6KB/s   00:00
```

I want to be able to manipulate that output, so I can notify the user that all the files (there are multiple files to upload) were upload correctly, or which were not.

I tried the solution in this answer [How to capture stdout output from a Python function call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571150/how-to-capture-stdout-output-from-a-python-function-call) but it didn't work. I tried Popen and subprocess and had no results as well. Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You should create a model, e.g. `Document`. with a `FileField` Attribute. But no idea how to create a model instance when `scp`'ing. The instance then notifies the user in a `view` and `template` with infos about correctness and copy time.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't directly answer your question, but I won't do the raw `scp` command in python because the output is hard to parse even if you have it. You should consider using tools like [`fabric`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/index.html) to handle this. It's pythonic and you have full control over the input/output. The operation same as `scp` is [`put`](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.11/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.put). For an example you could check this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314711/how-do-i-copy-a-directory-to-a-remote-machine-using-fabric?answertab=votes#tab-top).

<sub>Almost all command line operations can be done using `fabric`, you won't regret learning it.</sub>