# How to get files from Remote windows server to local Windows machine directory?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using a tool which will create files in remote windows 2012 servers continuously. I need to get those files and place it in a local directory.

```
import os
import time

def copy_logs():
    os.system(".\pscp.exe -pw test123 C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/tr* Administrator@1.1.1.1:/")
    time.sleep(7200)    
while True:
    copy_logs()
```

I have used 'pscp' inside python script to copy files. But I am unable to specify space/destination directory to copy the files into.

Is there anyway to achieve this with Python?

Comment: Please forget `os.system` and replace it by a more robust solution, i.e.: `subprocess.check_call`.

Comment: The destination directory is `/`: the root of the remote server (which is bad). The remote path should be specified like this: `Administrator@1.1.1.1:/path/to/the/destination/directory/`.

Comment: The documentation of `pscp` is available here: https://linux.die.net/man/1/pscp

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I know, is to use [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/). See: [How do I copy a directory to a remote machine using Fabric?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5314711).